# How to override the bundle product special price in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, bundled-product, special-price, bundle

I'm edit the file but not updated any change in admin side.can anyone please tell me which is correct file for edit bundle product special price.

```
vendor/magento/module-bundle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes/Special.php
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more what exactly are you trying and if possible please provide the screenshot for the same

Comment: I added the screenshot. In that screenshot I need to change the special price. because I'm passing the special price % to here and display the 4 decimals also

Comment: Is it possible to set fix special price instead of the percentage?

Answer (score 1):

This section is coming from customizeAdvancedPricing function which is in

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AdvancedPricing.php

And if you want to change special price field refer check modifyMeta function in below file

vendor/magento/module-bundle/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/BundleAdvancedPricing.php

Let me know if you have any query